# get the path of csv file located in hdfs using bash script and two parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Assume that I have this csv file in HDFS :

```
/hdfs/data/adhoc/PR/02/MGM7GM05-2019-08-16.csv
```

I should get this path using bash script and having as parameters :

1. the date : given by `2019-08-16`
2. the file's name : given by `MGM7GM05`

So I created this bash script to return the given path bellow :

```
#!/bin/bash

NOM_CRE="MGM7GM05"
echo "$NOM_CRE"
DATE="2019-08-16"
echo "$DATE"

HDFS_PATH=/hdfs/data/adhoc/PR/02/RDO0/BB0/$NOM_CRE-${DATE}.csv
echo"HDFS_PATH"
```

But this doesn't work at all.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question , I am interpreting that you need to find and echo out the file name , if date and file name are given as inputs.

Below might help:

```
#!/bin/bash

NOM_CRE='MGM7GM05'
Date='2019-08-16'
Base_HDFS_Path='/hdfs/data/adhoc/PR/02/RDO0/BB0/'
End_Path=$NOM_CRE'-'$DATE'.csv'

echo $Base_HDFS_Path$End_Path
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing a whitespace after `echo`:

```
echo"HDFS_PATH"
```

it should be:

```
echo "HDFS_PATH"
```

Second, you do not read the contents of the variable, so altogether it should be:

```
echo "$HDFS_PATH"
```